# why my zip returned item can't be applied set twice in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

To illustrate my question, here is a minimal code.

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = ['a','b','c']
m = zip(x,y)
print(set(m))
print(set(m))
```

I expect the second `print(set(m))` will generate the same result as the first `print(set(m))`, but here is what we got...

```
{(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')}
set()
```

If we replace the `set` to `list`, the result is the same. Any suggestion on why this happen?

Comment: Since Python 3, zip now returns a generator, not a list.  the first set call 'unwinds' the generator (consumes it).  It is empty for the next call.  To solve this, use m=list(zip(x,y)).

Answer (score 6):

Since Python 3, zip now returns a iterator, not a list.

Your first set call 'unwinds' the iterator referenced by m (consumes it).

It is empty for the next call.

To solve this, use

```
m=list(zip(x,y)).
```

Answer (score 2):

Zip returns an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip). We iterate through an iterator using the `__next__` method. Once the items have been exhausted, it raises the stop iteration exception.

On your first call of the `set` method, you exhaust the iterator. Therefore, when you make your second call to the iterator, there are no more items to iterate through, hence, returning an empty set.

Here's a [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) to how an iterator object is being implemented.